# React add label to nested array object in Object.keys map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a React component which is pulling JSON data via an axios.get call and then I am mapping an embedded object using the following function:

```
axios.get('MasterData.json').then(response => {
       const fullTree = response.data.graph.tree;
       const resultTree = Object.keys(fullTree).map(key => ({
          ...fullTree[key],
         id: key
    }));
```

This produces the following:

```
{5bd356cc-5ee6-49a0-ab68-65cbf0209105: Array(6), id: "5bd356cc-5ee6-49a0- ab68-65cbf0209105"}
```

which is great, but I need to add a label of "ports: to the entire nested array (Array(6)) that is being output above so that I can map it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use `({
          ports : ...fullTree[key],
         id: key
    })` instead of `({
          ...fullTree[key],
         id: key
    })`

Comment: What do you mean by 'add a label'? Can you add details on how the structure is now and what your expected output is?

Comment: Hassan I get a parsing error with your method (my first thought was to try that). Dinesh, what I am trying to do is exactly what I thought Hassan's code would do, which is give the entire array a key of "ports."

Answer (score 1):

```
axios.get('MasterData.json').then(response => {
   const fullTree = response.data.graph.tree;  
   console.log(fullTree) // you must check this fist
   const resultTree = Object.keys(fullTree).map(key => 
     new Port({  // create some function to generate get port as you want
        port : fullTree[key],
        id: key
     )
});
```

for create function maybe on bellow me can explain more :)